# Import many javascript files in a directory into Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

If I have a repository in `bower_components` containing a folder with 50 JS files, I cannot include them one at a time in my Brocfile with app.import(). How do I include them all in the same call?

If I try to app.import an entire directory of js files, I get this error on compilation:
`You must pass a file to 'app.import'. For directories specify them to the constructor under the 'trees' option.`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am having the similar issue and don't want to do it one by one at a time...Is it possible to use regex in app.import()?

Answer (score 1):

what you are loocking for is the broccoli-static-compiler npm package which manage this perfectly, you can get it there : https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-static-compiler and it's provieded with a nice documentation.

Comment: As far as I know, this is only for copying static files, not including scripts... am I wrong?

Comment: OK, but I don't want to COPY the scripts, I want to include them into the my app's master minified JS file.